# Add more colors to the framework

Tags: tailwind-css

[Suggestion]

Would there be a possibility to add more colors?
For example:

1. Orange.
2. Teal.
3. Cyan.

For the orange color, I suggest:

```
(SASS)
$orange-50:     #FFF7EF;
$orange-100:    #FEEBD5;
$orange-200:    #FECACA;
$orange-300:    #FCA5A5;
$orange-400:    #FA974B;
$orange-500:    #F27128;
$orange-600:    #DA4E16;
$orange-700:    #B73813;
$orange-800:    #962e15;
$orange-900:    #7C2916;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your custom colors in tailwind.config.js

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        orange: {
           100: "#FEEBD5",
           // add others that you want
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```